# Interpreting memtest results - 0 MHz?

Tags: memory, memtest86+

I have tried to install Ubuntu on a laptop width damaged Windows, and it gave me an error. After some checks, the only that give some strange results is memtest86+. I don't know how to interpret memtest results but, from my inexperience, this result looks strange:

[image: memtest screen]

Please help me interpreting memtest86+ results, is my RAM damaged?

Comment: *"is my RAM damaged? -- Maybe, since that is not a normal screen.  Try reseating each memory module (aka 'stick"), or just run with one module at a time (if there is more than one).  Bad memory could explain those other issues you mention.

Comment: Your version of Memtest86 is old and may not like your chipset. Get the newest version: http://www.memtest.org/

Comment: This is clearly a problem with memtest not able to detect the speed of your memory use the current version

Comment: I have download the last version and it works! Thanks!